# Is there an official/recommended way to organize CSS files for a responsive theme?

Tags: 7, theming

While creating a **responsive** theme (eg. a bootstrap based sub-theme) is there an **official/recommended** way to organize CSS files for different **media queries**? In general I put everything into one CSS file.

### 1. All In One

**mytheme.info:**

```
...
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
...
```

**style.css:**

```
body { ... }

p { ... }

...

@media (max-width: 767px) {
...
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
...
}
```

### 2. Separated CSS Files

**mytheme.info:**

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/480.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/720.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/960.css
```

**style.css, 480.css, 720.css ...**

### 3. Separate CSS Files for Each Media Query Defined in .info File

**mytheme.info:**

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
stylesheets[all and (min-width: 480px)][] = css/480.css
stylesheets[all and (min-width: 720px)][] = css/720.css
stylesheets[all and (min-width: 960px)][] = css/960.css
```

**style.css, 480.css, 720.css ...**

### 4. Other?

I wonder what is the recommended way for this or it doesn't matter (structural, performance wise etc).

Comment: I don't think there's any difference. And if there is, it will be so small it won't make any difference.

Comment: Using LESS I prefer store custom less code in separate file and other possible changes make in variables.less

Comment: Since you mention you are using Bootstrap, you could use LESS or Sass to separate your code in different files, and then on compilation they will become a single file (even compressed if you want to), thus reducing the problem of multiple http requests.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly hard to answer. But all the way are acceptable.

Mostly people don't like reading through a single HUGE CSS file, and maintaining it is very difficult. On the other hand, splitting it out causes extra http requests which could potentially slow things down.

*My opinion would be one of two things:*

1. If you know that your CSS will NEVER change once you've built it, I'd build multiple CSS files in the development stage (for readability), and then manually combine them before going live (to reduce http requests).
2. If you know that you're going to change your CSS once in a while, and need to keep it readable, I would build separate files and use code (providing you're using some sort of programming language) to combine them at build time (runtime minification/combination is a resource pig).

With either option I would highly recommend caching on the client side in order to further reduce http requests.

I also found another question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657159/when-using-media-queries-does-a-phone-load-non-relevent-queries-and-images . This will further clear your concept about this.

Comment: If you turn on CSS aggregation, point 1's performance gains for multi-https requests becomes obsolete. On point 2 I guess you're suggesting SASS/LESS? Runtime minification can be resource hog only if you're not caching it effectively.

Comment: it's described in the link i provided.

Comment: check out link it will help you.

Comment: Which is not relelvant to drupal at all. I'm speaking in relation to Drupal. Point 1 is not relevant at all, because when you turn on CSS aggregation, drupal will group your CSS files and reduce the HTTP requests.

Comment: Waqar Ali, I believe it is a recommended practice in Stackexchange to provide some details about what the links you put in your answers talk about. This is useful in case these links would disappear, and it makes your answer more useful and clear at first reading... Thank you.

Comment: ok, thanks for good suggestion. I will keep it in my mind next time